# Is there a way of identifying all posts related to each through a duplicate reference?

Tags: discussion, search, duplicate-questions

Of all the challenges of making SO effective, the challenge of handling duplicates seems to me to be among the most difficult and most important. We seem to be torn between wanting to retain if not encourage all the duplicates for any incremental value they might provide (e.g. for search) and wanting to focus the community on the "primary" question and its answers/comments.

In any event, given that this situation of non-deleted duplicates seems like it's going to be with us for a while, I was wondering if there was a way to do any one of the following:

- search for all questions which are related to each other through a duplicate reference
- search for all questions marked as duplicate of a single question
- see when looking at a question whether other questions are marked as a duplicate of that question

Comment: This is basically all in the sidebar of the question page already, under the "Linked" heading.

Comment: @CodyGray, but it also includes other questions (not duplicats) mentioned in the question

Comment: Thanks to you both for your comments. Can one of you explain the difference between "Linked" and "Related", or should I pose that as a separate question? (My search for the answer came up short.)

Comment: Linked are posts that are explicitly linked (through suggestions as duplicate, or otherwise connecting to the current post - like a followup post that mentions the current post).  Related are posts with common keywords that might be relevant (potential duplicates, or just useful information on the same subject).